# Full 16+ DVD Linux Debian 10 / buster on one USB 128GB drive

Tags: linux, debian, system-installation, usb-drive

I know I can install the first Linux Debian DVD on a USB flash drive, but I'd like to install all 16 + 2 update DVDs worth on a handful of PCs, so that I don't have to create 18 DVDs, etc. and insert them into each PC one at a time.

So can all 18 ISOs be put on a 128GB USB flash drive after creating the bootable image of the first DVD?  If so, then how?  Just copy the contents of the rest (DVDs 2 through 18) of the ISOs to the USB flash drive?  Or...?

If there are instructions for this already, then I'm not picking the right keywords for it.  (I keep getting instructions for creating a bootable USB drive of just the first ISO, and only that.)

To be clear, I don't want to use this USB flash drive as my Linux installation, I don't need a "live" USB image with persistence to use all the time.  I want it only so I can install all 18 DVDs worth of Linux Debian "buster" onto several (3 to 5) PCs more easily; download / jigdo all 18 images, copy to / install onto USB stick once, stick in USB flash drive once into each PC, boot, install everything I want (onto each PC's HDD.)

Alternatively, is there a complete (60GB+) image I can jigdo and get onto a 128GB USB flash drive?  TIA

Comment: It's possible, because you can [buy one](https://linuxcollections.com/products/debian/debianusb.htm?id=51007), but I don't know how they built it.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows app [YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) allows multiple ISOs to be installed as LiveUSB images on one USB device, and will work under WINE.

[Multisystem](https://sourceforge.net/projects/multisystem/) also gives you this capability.